# Reg expression to exclude string with % char in it

Tags: regex

I want to match all the instances of **filter[ ... ]** but excluding the ones that have a % char in them:

```
filter[first_name%0]=Tim&filter[first_name]=Tom&filter[first_name]=Bob
```

The `/filter\[.*?\]/i` gets all of the instances but how do I exclude the one with % in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
filter\[[^\][%]*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BnzXgC/2)

*Details*

- `filter\[` - a `filter[` string
- `[^\][%]*` - zero or more (`*`) chars that are not equal to `]`, `[` and `%`
- `]`  - a literal `]` char.